# Consul cluster doesn't start

Tags: consul

I have an AWS launch configuration for a Consul cluster. Up until now it ran with no problem, but now it doesn't work. Querying any node results in "no leader elected".

So I SSH'd into the instance. `consul info` results in `Error querying agent: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/self: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: getsockopt: connection refused`.

Next I tried: 

`$ ps -ef | grep consul
consul    2760     1  0 Nov28 ?        00:01:38 /usr/local/bin/consul agent -server -config-file=/etc/consul.conf -data-dir=/tmp/consul -node=1.1.1.1_i-042b3e8f28c622a -bind=2.2.2.2 -config-dir=/etc/consul.d`
 (I've hidden the IP and instance IDs here)

Looking at the log I see:

```
==> WARNING: Expect Mode enabled, expecting 3 servers
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Consul agent running!
           Version: 'v0.8.3'
           Node ID: '6e0b3c-ad49-90d7-c8e2-121144a4ba'
         Node name: '1.1.1.1_i-029b3e8f28622a'
        Datacenter: 'dc1'
            Server: true (bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: 127.0.0.1 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 2.2.2.2 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
    Gossip encrypt: false, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
             Atlas: <disabled>

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] raft: Initial configuration (index=0): []
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 1.1.1.1_i-029b3e8f28c46622a 2.2.2.2
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 1.1.1.1_i-029b3e8f28c46622a.dc1 2.2.2.2
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] raft: Node at 2.2.2.2:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state (Leader: "")
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] consul: Adding LAN server 1.1.1.1_i-029b3e8f28c46622a (Addr: tcp/2.2.2.2:8300) (DC: dc1)
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] consul: Handled member-join event for server "1.1.1.1_i-029b3e8f28c22a.dc1" in area "wan"
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] agent: Joining cluster...
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] agent: No EC2 region provided, querying instance metadata endpoint...
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [INFO] agent: Discovered 0 servers from EC2
    2017/11/28 13:19:36 [WARN] agent: Join failed: No servers to join, retrying in 30s
    2017/11/28 13:19:43 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should bootstrap the cluster to allow initial leader election, easiest way is to use `-bootstrap-expect` with the number of servers in the cluster (use the same flag and value for all servers).

More info about bootstrapping a cluster - https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/bootstrapping.html

and https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_bootstrap

in your case it says "WARNING: Expect Mode enabled, expecting 3 servers" so it expects 3 servers before bootstraping the cluster. I see that you use only two? join another one and it should work... (less than 3 isn't recommended for consensus systems).

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way, you can use -bootstrap to specify a server node. This eliminates the need to start 3 servers to boot the consul cluster pick leader.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed explanation for Ubuntu - +AWS :

1. Your file should like this :/etc/consul/base.json

```js
 {
    "server": true,
    "ui": true,
    "bootstrap_expect":3,
    "bind_addr": "102.102.3.1",
    "performance": { "raft_multiplier": 1 },
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "retry_join": [ "provider=aws tag_key=HostIdentifier tag_value=us1-Consul-Prod addr_type=private_v4" ],
    "disable_remote_exec": true,
    "log_level":  "DEBUG",
    "data_dir":   "/var/lib/consul",
    "recursors": ["1.1.1.1"],
    "datacenter": "us1"
}
```

(retry_join - optional if you're using ec2 tagging), make sure you have IAM role attached to instance)

2. service consul restart
3. Run - #consul operator raft list-peers
   you should see leader, else check /var/log/syslog for more details to troubleshoot